# clonoNode() Dom method unable to Clone given Xml Doc Object

Tags: javascript, clonenode

When i trying to Clone Xml Document Object Chrome,IE behaves properly but Safari Browser version 5.1.7 which returns null,

Follwing is my sample Code
**xml string**

```
var xmlStr="<tr> <td class="dsd">  </td><td class='name'></td></tr>"

var doc=getXmlDoc(xmlStr) (i.e getXmlDoc is my custom function which returns string to doc using DOM Parser)

funtion getXmlDoc(str)
{
parser = new DOMParser();  
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(str,"text/xml");
return xmlDoc
}

doc-Document(converted Document)

 d.cloneNode(true)-Returns null


   When i try to clone Entire Document,unable to clone
But d.documentElement.cloneNode(true) works
```

But when i try to clone root node , i can.

This Issue only in Safari Browser 5.1.7 Tested.

```
I am working on ExtJs Framework, where EXt.clone() also returns null
```

Thanks in advance,
Praveenkumar

Comment: doc-Document(converted Document)

 doc.cloneNode(true)-Returns null  , i wrongly typed, its doc.clone not d.clone. Safari not cloning anyway,, i cant use other framework.  except extjs.  is there any funtction that can clone

Answer (score 0):

Since Safari doesnt clone the Entire Document, but it still clone(supports) documentElement . For Example

```
var xmlStr="<tr> <td class="dsd">  </td><td class='name'></td></tr>";
//convert the above string into document
//funtion getXmlDoc(str)
{
parser = new DOMParser();  
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(str,"text/xml");
return xmlDoc
}


var newDoc=getXmlDoc(str);
//after Converting str to newDoc 
var copy=newDoc.cloneNode(true);//will return error
//Let see How to Done
var copy=getXmlDoc(getXmlStr(newDoc.documentElement.cloneNode(true)));
```

Explanation
 CloneNode method clones a given element, but we need to clone a document so, first we clone elements and convert them string then convert them Doc.

But it seems little memory consuming,
anyhow anyone provide better solution.